# Need help solving a surface integral question

Tags: surface-integrals

The question is:
[image: picture of question]
I understand the method used in the book. However, when I try a slightly different method, I end up with an incorrect answer: 2$\pi$ instead of 4$\pi$ as given in the book.
[image: picture of attempted solution]
I have already tried looking for what I could be going wrong but no avail. Hence decided to ask here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to calculate $\int\int_S dA$. So half of it will be given by the parametrization $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, \sqrt{a^2 - x^2 - y^2})$, for $x^2 + y^2 \le a^2$.

Then the area element is given by

$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2 - y^2}}dxdy =  \frac{ar}{\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}} dr d\theta$$

So

$$ \int \int_S dA = \frac{2}{a} \int_{x^2 + y^2 \le a^2}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2 -  y^2}}$$

That is, you only forgot the 2 there.

Comment: Thank you! Still can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote out an expression for $dS$, it appears that you're only integrating over the top half of the sphere.